# How to Isolate Silverlight Memory Leaks

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks, telerik

I have a memory leak in a silverlight app, I used this information to get started,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slperf/archive/2010/08/19/analyzing-silverlight-memory-usage-part-1-obtaining-measurements.aspx

Which was excellent. I have extracted some of my code to break down the issue. So the code looks like this, a child window,

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="MemoryLeakTesting2.ConfirmDialog"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"        
       Width="375"   >
    <Grid Margin="2">
        <telerik:RadButton Content="OK" Click="OnClick" Command="{Binding CancelActionCommand}" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</controls:ChildWindow>
```

The code behind is this,

```
public partial class ConfirmDialog : ChildWindow
{
    public ConfirmDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

I am calling this code from the button click event in my main silverlight page like this,

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog();
    dialog.Show();
}
```

This leaks memory every time I open the popup and close it. I use WinDbg and it actually shows that the ConfirmDialog instance is not freed after each time it is popped up and closed??

Comment: how do you know that the memory is leaking for sure? Can you actually see the memory consumption going up? (where?)

Comment: I've updated the question. The ConfirmDialog is not being freed each time it is created and the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The `Button.Command` is notorious for leaking. My guess is that the value `CancelActionCommand` has a reference to a long lived object. The `Button` won't unhook from the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event. You should consider using a [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) to limit your leakable surface area.

[Here is a better explanation and example code to fix the problem.](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/177550/446111.aspx)

Comment: You may be correct with regard to our overall application, but for this particular code snippet above I just copied and pasted some code from our app. The actual command there is not bound to anything. There is no view model.

Comment: Worth a long shot... is there something in the Styles.xaml or other ResourceDictionary that applies to the window or button implicitly?

Comment: Well that's the funny thing. All I did was create a blank silverlight 4 solution. Copy in the child window above from our main product, removed some of the other stuff in the child window, and that's it. No styles or anything.

Comment: Nice. Real confidence builder there.

Comment: This might be a better question for Microsoft to answer. They keep building useless filth like this, ruining the interwebs. Can you not build your app in Flash or HTML5 or both?

Comment: @dmf85: And those (flash/html5) are memory leak proof?

Comment: Ummm yep. Good comments. I am trying to stir up some action from M$ about this - silverlight seems flaky and memory leak prone to me as this is just a very specific problem I am having, but there are more. I put my question on the silverlight forum too, they asked me for some code, and when I supplied it they never did anything more. The only way to build my 'thing' in flash or html5 would be to resign and move on to my next job.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

On every click event you are creating `ConfirmDialog` object, which might hang around after it is no longer being used. Can you create that as a class variable and only have one reference and use that instead when you need to show the `ChildWindow`

Comment: Why would it be hanging around? Perhaps you are right, but just exploring the idea a bit more. How about I go away and measure one way or the other. Watch this space.

Comment: Scan Thread 5 OSTHread 11c4
Scan Thread 34 OSTHread 12f8
Scan Thread 35 OSTHread 108c
DOMAIN(07581358):HANDLE(Pinned):81d12f8:Root:  0ce74260(System.Object[])->
  0be86958(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]])->
  0befcbc4(System.Object[])->
  0bf17df4(MemoryLeakTesting2.ConfirmDialog)

Comment: Sorry - that looks terrible, but the bounty is closing soon. I think you are right that it is being held open, and the above is a stack trace of what is holding it open. I cannot understand what is holding it open?

Comment: @peter: see ChildWindow memory leak (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/4753?ProjectName=silverlight) - For some reason I thought this would've been fixed with SL4, but maybe not...I will update this if I come across something interesting.